# Concurrent Consumers in JMS publisher/ Subscriber model

Tags: java, concurrency, publish-subscribe, spring-jms

I am using pub/sub model with a DefaultMessageListenerContainer. I have configured concurrent consumers to 5. How can I uniquely identify each consumer?

I am trying to store each event processed by corresponding listener in a map. This is the part where I am struggling to find which consumer has processed my event. How can I do this?

The key thing is how to identify a consumer uniquely in a concurrent consumer situation. 
My configuration for DMLC is

```
@Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainers() {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        container.setDestinationName(COMMENT_QUEUE);
        container.setPubSubDomain(true);
        container.setSessionTransacted(true);
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(5);
        container.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        container.setMessageListener(datafileSubscriber);
        container.start();
        return container;
    }
```

As you know this will make datafilesubscriber execute in 5 different threads. 
EDIT :
I heard that we need a connectionfactory with a separate client ID.

```
  @Bean
        public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
            connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
            connectionFactory.setClientID("subscriber");
            return connectionFactory;
        }
```

So now my question is what should I do with connectionFactory argument in my dmlc? Should I use the same connectionFactory bean or create 5 different one's with different client ID's.

EDIT 2:
My sample code for 2 listeners subscribed to the same topic and both are durable consumers. When a message is published to the topic, both of them receive the message and one of them processes it while the other ignores it because it saw in a cache that the another listener processed it. 
My configuration is

```
@Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
        return connectionFactory;
    }
@Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainers() {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        //container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory1());
        container.setClientId("consumer1");
        container.setDestinationName(COMMENT_QUEUE);
        container.setPubSubDomain(true);
        container.setSessionTransacted(true);
        container.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        container.setMessageListener(datafileSubscriber);
        container.start();
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainers1() {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        container.setClientId("consumer2");
        container.setDestinationName(COMMENT_QUEUE);
        container.setPubSubDomain(true);
        container.setSessionTransacted(true);
        container.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        container.setMessageListener(datafileSubscriber);
        container.start();
        return container;
    }
```

My question remains the same, how do I identify which listener is processing since both the listeners execute the same?

Also tell me if my configuration is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Using concurrency with a topic doesn't make much sense since the message listener will get the same message 5 times.

If that's really what you want, you need 5 containers with concurrency=1.

Standard JMS doesn't support competing consumers on topics (some brokers have extensions for that but you would have to refer to your broker's documentation for that).

Comment: Actually I want to make those consumers durable. Does my configuration even work? Can you suggest a way where all the 5 consumers receive the message and they are durable and I must be able to identify them ?

Comment: Can you see the EDIT part and clarify on required ConnectionFactory?

Comment: As long as you use a simple ConnectionFactory like that, you can set the clientId on the container instead of on the factory. Or you can use 5 CFs.

Comment: Hey Gary, look at edit 2. Please answer the question.

Comment: You'll need a separate listener instance for each and also configure it with client id. That said, this use case seems strange to me. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Like I said, I need multiple listeners that execute the same code. I want the listeners to be durable in a publisher/ subscribe model.

Comment: How do I configure listener with client ID? I didnt get that . Can you demonstrate that?

Comment: You need to add a property to your listener and set it to the same value as the container's client I'd. Yes, you said that but in your edit you said the second consumer ignored it because the first one already processed it. Confusing. You need to be much more precise in your problem description.

Comment: Gary, can you take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549249/multiple-listeners-that-are-durable-do-they-work-concurrently